# controlar avançar e voltar do navegador

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, funções

preciso fazer com que o sistema não permita avançar ou retroceder quando pressionado o backspace, alguém pode me ajudar por gentileza?

Aguardo!

Comment: O usuário sempre pode voltar a página pelo botão "Voltar" do navegador. Quando isso acontece o evento `window.onbeforeunload` é disparado mas você não pode interromper a ação. Mais informações [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload).

Comment: cara preciso disso sei que tem como fazer, mas não lembro como, utilizei uma vez em um sistema que hoje já não tenho mais em mãos, mas sei que tem como fazer, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Se você quer evitar a navegação entre páginas do seu sistema, faça uma SPA. Já se você quer remover uma liberdade fundamental do usuário, tire umas férias e use o tempo para repensar a sua vida.

Answer (score -1):

Galera consegui resolver:

```
$(document).unbind('keydown').bind('keydown', function(event) {
    var doPrevent = false;
    if (event.keyCode === 8) {
        var d = event.srcElement || event.target;
        if ((d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT' && (d.type.toUpperCase() === 'TEXT' || d.type.toUpperCase() === 'PASSWORD' || d.type.toUpperCase() === 'EMAIL' || d.type.toUpperCase() === 'SEARCH' || d.type.toUpperCase() === 'FILE')) || d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'TEXTAREA') {
            doPrevent = d.readOnly || d.disabled;
        } else {
            doPrevent = true;
        }
    }
    if (doPrevent) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: quando não está dentro de algum campo ele bloqueia o backspace, impedindo assim que o sistema volte para a pagina anterior, pois caso o usuário tenha efetivado uma alteração em algum campo ele vai perder dessa forma, isso ajuda, pq se ele clicar no voltar ai é outros quinhentos haha

Comment: testou em quantos navegadores?

Comment: só que a resposta só é válida no retroceder (voltar) o avançar não resolve   ( também não resolve caso o usuário use alt+seta esquerda )

Comment: Testou com o botão "Voltar" do navegador?

Comment: @Nevershowmyface creio que [o comment dele](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115162/controlar-avan%c3%a7ar-e-voltar-do-navegador#comment240144_115188) já responde isso :), o que ele quer é evitar o usuário voltar sem querer ao corrigir um campo texto. Esse é um dos vários males de se usar "ambiente web" como se fosse aplicação de verdade.